# Samba and Snapper

Tags: linux, samba

I managed to create a samba share for profiles with something like this

```
[global]
    ...
    vfs objects = acl_xattr btrfs snapper
    ...

[Profiles]
    path = /srv/samba/profiles
    read only = no
```

and the snapper config

```
SUBVOLUME="/srv/samba"
FSTYPE="btrfs"
ALLOW_USERS=""
ALLOW_GROUPS="domänen-benutzer" # (yes, it's a german AD, not my fault.. :/ )
SYNC_ACL="yes"
...
```

Also the .snapshot folder has

```
# ls -lha
...
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 root domänen-benutzer  570 26. Sep 12:00 .snapshots
```

Now I can (as a arbitrary user) exec `snapper -c samba list` and it works and will list all snapshots, also I can execute `snapper -c samba diff .....` and it will list me the difference between two snapshots (only for that user of course and if I log in as an domain-admin it will list all diffs).

The only problem now is, that I cannot see snapshots in the windows explorer, as it should be :/ Does anyone has a solution for this? I mean, I follwed the guide in the `man 8 vfs_snapper` and it works but not for the explorer itself.

Ps. I would like to have a new tag `snapper`, but I don't have the required 300 rep to do so, if anyone could add this please and remove this ps :) thanks

Comment: I don't know if it is applicable to Linux/btrfs, but on Solaris/ZFS, you specify the mapping of groups regardless of domain language (as internally, Windows Server as well as Samba4 map *Domain Users*, *Domain Administrators*, *Power Users* and the other reserved names to the displayed language).

Comment: I assume you followed documentation similar to https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/book_sle_admin/data/samba_advanced.html ? Are there any ACL entries that might deny access (they work on top of your basic permissions)?

Comment: You might be running into a subtree limitation within Samba. Can you view any nested BTRFS subvolumes on the Windows hosts? Snapshots being a new subvolume, and all.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue (thanks to the comments :D )
The problem was, that the samba share and the snapshot were not in the same directory (/srv/samba vs /srv/samba/profiles). They have to be in the exact same spot, that's the mystery.